# Basic (arithmetic) operations and their dependence on JVM and CPU

Tags: java, performance, jvm, cpu, milliseconds

In Java I want to measure time for

1. 1000 integer comparisons ("<" operator),
2. 1000 integer additions (a+b
   each case for different a and b),
3. another simple operations.

I know I can do it in the following way:

```
Random rand = new Random();
long elapsedTime = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    int a = Integer.MIN_VALUE + rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    int b = Integer.MIN_VALUE + rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (a < b) {}
    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    elapsedTime += (start - stop);
}
System.out.println(elapsedTime);
```

I know that this question may seem somehow not clear.

How those values depend on my processor (i.e. relation between time for those operations and my processor) and JVM? Any suggestions?

I'm looking for understandable readings...

Comment: Your code will not produce reliable benchmark for many reasons. Among them: JVM will optimize the code, so `if(a <b) {}` may be skipped; modern JVM will switch from interpreting to compiling code so you have to *warm up* the JVM; using `random` in a benchmark is definitively a bad idea, even if provided with a seed; and many more. You may want to look at JHM: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I see what you mean having run my own code. Any other suggestions how to measure the elapsed time?

Comment: This isn't very useful, and ultimately it never really will be. If you want to reliably benchmark simple instructions on your CPU, you should write the benchmark in assembly. Even then it may not be trivial to design a benchmark that tests what you wanted to test, particularly if you want to test a branch.

Comment: Are you benchmarking the JRE or the CPU?

Comment: @jdv Both, in 2 passes of course. But as harold suggested it would be better to benchmark the CPU in a low-level language.

Comment: Yeah. CPU benchmarks aren't well served with higher abstraction languages. Many benchmarks I've seen use the CPU vendor C compiler or assembler. For example, most Intel/AMD type CPUs are often seen benchmarked with the Intel compiler. For JVM benchmarks, one of the most accessible references I have ever read is "Java Performance: The Definitive Guide".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How those values depend on my processor (i.e. relation between time for those operations and my processor) and JVM? Any suggestions?

It is not dependant on your processor, at least not directly.

Normally, when you run code enough, it will compile it to native code.  When it does this, it removes code which doesn't do anything, so what you will be doing here is measuring the time it takes to perform a `System.currentMillis()`, which is typically about 0.00003 ms.  This means you will get `0` 99.997% of the time and see a 1 very rarely.

I say normally, but in this case your code won't be compiled to native code, as the default threshold is 10,000 iterations.  I.e. you would be testing how long it takes the interpretor to execute the byte code.  This is much slower, but would still be a fraction of a milli-second. i.e. you have higher chance seeing a `1` but still unlikely.

If you want to learn more about low level benchmarking in Java, I suggest you read [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and the Author's blog http://shipilev.net/

If you want to see what machine code is generated from Java code I suggest you try [JITWatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch/)